# Django RedirectView with missing variables

Tags: django

Hello I want to redirect the urls like `/{category}/{sub_category}` to `/{category}/` but RedirectView wants to resolve the url with both subcategory and category keyword arguments

```
url(r'^/(?P<category_slug>[^\/]+)/$', CategoryView.as_view(), name='category'),

url(r'^/(?P<category_slug>[^\/]+)/(?P<another_parameter>[^\/]+)$',
    RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='category')),
```

so this doesn't work, I think default should be ignoring unrequired parameters..

I am getting `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch:`

What would be the best option to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`pattern_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.pattern_name), Django will try to reverse with the same args and kwargs as were passed in to the view. This doesn't work for you, because you want to redirect to the `category` view which only takes `category_slug`.

You can subclass `RedirectView` and override `get_success_url`.

```
from django.urls import reverse

class CategoryRedirectView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self):
        return reverse('category', args=(self.kwargs['category'],))
```

Then use `CategoryRedirectView` in your urls instead of `RedirectView`.

```
url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[^\/]+)/(?P<another_parameter>[^\/]+)$',
CategoryRedirectView.as_view()),
```

Note that I've removed the leading slash. You would only need it you are using `include()` without a trailing slash. You definitely don't need the leading slash in the root url conf.

Comment: That's the way I implemented but hoped for a better way :/ Thanks for clearing it out.